# Alert modal from sidebar close(X) icon

Tags: css, angular, primeng, sidebar

I am using `p-sidebar` to display a component as a sidebar from another component. Now when the sidebar displays, it has a `close(X)` icon at the top right corner and clicking on it closes the sidebar. I want to display a alert modal when clicked in `close(X)` icon.

```
<p-sidebar [(visible)]="slideBarDisplay"
             [style]="{'height':'75%','overflow':'scroll'}"
             position="bottom">
    <sidebar-component (add)="addNew($event)"
                              (cancelAdd)="slideBarDisplay = false"
                              *ngIf="slideBarDisplay">
    </sidebar-component>
  </p-sidebar>
```

and I have `showClearModal = false;` to display the modal in `sidebar-component` html.

So I want to call

```
showAlertDisplay() {
this.showClearModal = true
}
```

when clicked on `close(X)` button so it will make `p-dialog` visible.

Appreacite any help

Comment: Have you tried to use `onHide` event ?

Comment: @Antikhippe if I use ```onHide``` from p-sidebar, then I have to put ```p-dialog``` in base components html not in ```sidebar-component```. I have ```p-dialog``` in ```sidebar-component``` as I also have Close button in ```sidebar-component``` which will show p-dialog when clicked on close button. Now I also have to put p-dialog both components. Or is there way to pass a boolean value to ```sidebar-component``` when onHide event triggered

Comment: "Or is there way to pass a boolean value to sidebar-component when onHide event triggered". Yes, you can use an `Input` in your `sidebar-component` to do such a thing.

Comment: That will not work. Now when onHide is called. I have to call a method to update a boolean on base component, then have that value as input value in sidebar-component. Now when the siderbar is closed, it triggered the event to update the value but the sidebar is already closed